# Cairo Dock opens folders just minimized

Tags: unity, nautilus, cairo-dock

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I click on the Files icon on Cairo Dock or select a folder in Shortcuts, the file window doesn't popup, instead it opens the folder minimized. However, I expect the window to be maximized after clicking. Similar problem is reported [here](http://w3facility.org/question/cairo-dock-opens-nautilus-minimized/).

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for the problem. 
In CompizConfig Settings Manager > General > General Options, turn Focus prevention level OFF.

Comment: I used to see a minimized "Downloads" folder open using "Open containing folder" in firefox downloads list. This method fixed that for me. This should be the accepted answer.